# How to store / fetch a struct with Redis in Rust?

Tags: redis, rust

I'm trying to figure out how to

1. programically instantiate a struct with set values (one of those might be yet another nested struct - or not) - **and save it in [Redis](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/redis-rs)**.
2. fetch it back into a struct from Redis

I am aware that the 2 traits `ToRedisArgs` and `FromRedisValue` are to be implemented here, but even for my very simple 2 structs I have no clue what to write to impl them in Rust. I've made a simple example:

```
extern crate redis;
use redis::Commands;

// fn fetch_an_integer() -> redis::RedisResult<isize> {
//     // connect to redis
//     let client = try!(redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/"));
//     let con = try!(client.get_connection());
//     // throw away the result, just make sure it does not fail
//     let _ : () = try!(con.set("my_key", 42));
//     // read back the key and return it.  Because the return value
//     // from the function is a result for integer this will automatically
//     // convert into one.
//     con.get("my_key")
// }

fn fetch_a_struct() -> redis::RedisResult<MyStruct> {
    // connect to redis
    let client = try!(redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/"));
    let con = try!(client.get_connection());
    // throw away the result, just make sure it does not fail

    let another_struct = AnotherStruct{x: "another_struct".to_string()};
    let mut my_vec: Vec<AnotherStruct> = Vec::new();
    my_vec.push(another_struct);
    let my_struct = MyStruct{x: "my_struct".to_string(), y: 1, z: my_vec};

    let _ : () = try!(con.set("my_key_struct", my_struct));

    con.get("my_key_struct")
}

fn main() {
    match fetch_a_struct() {
        Err(err) => {
            println!("{}", err)
        },
        Ok(x) => {
            println!("{}", x.x)
        }
    }

}

struct MyStruct {
    x: String,
    y: i64,
    z: Vec<AnotherStruct>,
}

struct AnotherStruct {
    x: String
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=75b7e0c99b310720462e0653071aa5c3&version=stable&backtrace=0))

I need to save different visitors, their browsing behavior (duration, pages visited and other interactions etc) and other stats while they browse around my website - That's why I was thinking about using Redis instead of MongoDB, as my outproc session store.

In MongoDB I'd have a user collection, interactions collection etc... but what might the equivalent way in Redis be?

Being a complete newbie at both Redis and Rust I hope you can help me at least to get a few ideas how to achieve something like this.

Comment: It seems like you are really asking "how do I store *this type of data* in Redis" in addition to "how do I store data in Redis *using Rust*". MongoDB, Redis, and traditional relational databases all have different strengths and they aren't necessarily substitutes for each other. I'd say that "how do I store this type of data" is **too broad** for Stack Overflow, so I'd recommend you remove that from your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Serialize your data to a JSON string](http://siciarz.net/24-days-of-rust-working-json/), save it as a string and then deserialize it when needed.

Comment: I'm afraid this would not work well for me, since the whole point of using redis over mongodb for realtime storage of visitor session state data is - increased speed. I'm kinda building something similar to how sitecore shared and private session works, where they gather data about the users behavior, and transferring this data to a database once the session expires. So a lot of reading and updating will happen to the session data, which is why json string serialization is not an option. But thanks for your answer anyways. :-)